# Is Facebook SDK Javascript consuming a lot of memory on my site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook, performance

I have a WordPress site which display some text and images. I think it's pretty standard. When I open my Task Manager in Chrome Canary latest version which is (43.0.2343.5) My site is hovering around 250MB which I think it's pretty high compared to other site. So I use Chrome Dev Tool to create a Heap snapshot and this is the result

[image]

And this is the Timeline result

[image]

And this is how I include Facebook plugin which I think it's pretty standard except I could change to be Async.

But the result of memory consumption is the same and for a simple wordpress site 250MB is pretty high. Am I on the right path to identify memory leak on my site?

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'facebook-api', '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=' . $app_id . '&version=v2.0' );
```

This is what my Task Manager shows

[image]

I use Google Chrome Canary with no Extension.

Comment: What if you click several times on a garbage collection button?

Comment: i don't see a leak based on your timeline...

Comment: What about if I want to identify why my site is using a lot of memory?

Comment: @toy on the timeline it states it's a ~40Mb page.

Comment: @zerkms so it's showing a different memory than Chrome Task Manager?

Comment: @toy on the task manager it's the whole process memory size, which includes all plugins, extensions, own chrome structures, etc

Comment: I've edited the question to include the picture of my Task Manager which has Javascript Memory as well. @zerkms

Comment: @toy it states JS consumes 48Mb.

Comment: Should I be concerned about that Chrome memory usage even though I'm not using any plugins or extension?

Comment: How is this related to Facebook SDK?